# changing the background colour of a recaptcha form that is placed in a DIV

Tags: php, css, html, colors, recaptcha

So i have a recaptcha form in a DIV. Currently the DIV has the background colour of white and the rest of my webpage is grey.

Where the recaptcha form is the white background is not displaying, but showing the grey colour instead.

The code i have for the recaptcha is in the DIV:

```
<div id="register">
<form action='register.php' method='post'>
 <h1>Register Here:</h1>
<h1><?php echo $message; ?></h1>
Username:<input type='text' name='username'
                value='<?php echo $username; ?>'><br />
Password:<input type='password' name='password'><br />
Repeat Password:<input type='password' name = 'repeatpassword' >  
  <?php echo $recaptcha_form; ?>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'>
<input name ='reset' type='reset' value='Reset'>
</form>
<h1>Once you have registered, log in  <a href='login.php'>here!</a></h1>

</div>
```

And the CSS i have used is:

```
#login, #register, #home {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 600px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: solid;
 border-color: #00ae00;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
Padding-top: 10px;
text-align:center;

}
```

Below is more of the recaptcha code:

```
 require_once('recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "6Lem4-gSAAAAAMHLAVbieIknMtUZo71ZKzzCkoFN";
$privatekey = "6Lem4-gSAAAAADsaa9KXlzSAhLs8Ztp83Lt-x1kn"; 
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
$recaptcha_form = recaptcha_get_html($publickey);

//grab the form data
$submit = trim($_POST['submit']);
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);
$repeatpassword = trim($_POST['repeatpassword']);



$message ='';
$s_usename ='';

//start to use PHP session

//determine whether user is logged in - test for vlaue in $_SESSION 
if (isset($_SESSION['logged'])){
    $s_username =$_SESSION['username'];
    $message = "You are already logged in as $s_username.<br />
                Please <a href='logout.php'>logout</a> before trying to       register.";

}else{ 
//next block of code

if ($submit=='Register'){
    //process submission 
    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        //what happens when the capture was entered incorrectly


        $errMessage =$resp->error;
        $message = "<strong>The recaptcha wasn't entered
                            correctly. Please try again.</strong>   <br />" . 
                            "(recaptcha said: $errMessage)<br />"; 
    }else{ 
        //process valid submission data here
        if ($username&&$password&&$repeatpassword){
            if ($password==$repeatpassword){
                //process username details here
                if (strlen($username)>25 )  {
                            $message= "Username is too long";
                }else{ 
                    if (strlen($password)>25||strlen($password)<6) {
                            $message = "Password must be between 6-25 characters long";
                    }else{ 
                    //process details here
                    require_once("db_connect.php"); //include file to do db  connect
                    if($db_server){
                            //clean the input not that we have a db connection
                            $username = clean_string($db_server, $username);
                            $password = clean_string($db_server, $password);
                            $repeatpassword = clean_string($db_server, $repeatpassword); 
                            mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
                            //cheach whther username exsists 
                            $query="SELECT username FROM register WHERE username='$username'";
                            $result=mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
                            if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                $message = "Username already exists. Please try again.";
                            }else{
                                //process further here
                                //Encrypt password
                                $password = salt($password);
                                $query = "INSERT INTO register (username, password) VALUES
                                                            ('$username', '$password')";
                                mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or
                                                die("Insert failed. ".mysqli_error($db_server));
                                $message = "<strong>Registration Successful!</strong>";
                            }
                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                    }else{
                        $message ="error: could not connect to the database.";
                    }
                    require_once("db_close.php"); //include file to do db close



                    }
                }
            }else{
                $message = "Both passwords fields must match";
            }
        }else{
            $message = "Please fill in all fields";
        }
    }
}
}

?>
```

Any idea what i can do which will colour the background area of the recapture form white?

please bare in mind im quire new to coding!

many thanks

Comment: Can you show the content of `$recaptcha_form`?

Comment: If `$recaptcha_form` resolves to an `iframe`, there's probably nothing you can do...

Comment: Please post the resulting markup of the captcha.

Answer (score 0):

Without having the recaptcha code, you can style it with this CSS:

```
#recaptcha_response_field { background: #fff !important; }
```

OR

you can use:

```
input[type=text] { background-color: #fff !important; }
```

Comment: You should use `background-color` instead of `background`. Also, try to avoid `!important` where possible!

Comment: Yeah, but without seeing the form code, and if the background-color is set in the php code. Then I just used !important, but you are right that you should avoid using '!important' when possible

Comment: Just tried both of these and no change. any ideas now ice added the recaptcha code for you to see? thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param

there is a light dark setting